# SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment for android closing keyboard on each key press

Tags: android, google-places

I'm developing an android app using google place autocomplete (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment).
On some devices I experienced this problem: when the user try to write an address the android keyboard close after every touch so it is not possible to write a full address. On other devices the autocomplete works fine.
Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue... Did you fix that?

Comment: unfortunately not. I tried with the intent version (OPTION 2 in https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete). That solved the problem on 1 device but not on all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used a wrong SHA1 certificate (I used the debug instead the one used for signing the app) in Google API Console when creating the API! Once the SHA1 certificate was correct everything started to work good.